# Programmatically select a tab of a Codename One Tabs object

Tags: codenameone

To programmatically select a tab of a Codename One Tabs object, the following code is enough:

```
tabs.setSelectedIndex(tabToSelect, true);
```

The problem is that this code selects the wanted tab but it doesn't horizontally scroll the tabs buttons container to make the tab name visible *(if it's not visible because there are many tabs)*. Note that I'm using the theme constant `tabsGridBool: false;`.

Because of this issue, I tried to solve so:

```
tabs.setSelectedIndex(tabToSelect, true);
tabs.scrollComponentToVisible(tabs.getTabsContainer().getComponentAt(tabToSelect));
```

but it doesn't work. What is a proper way to select a tab and its button? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this and it worked for me, it might be the order of the operations:

```
Form hi = new Form("Tabs", new BorderLayout());
Tabs t = new Tabs();
hi.add(CENTER, t);

for(int iter = 1 ; iter < 20 ; iter++) {
    t.addTab("Tab " + iter, FontImage.MATERIAL_ACCESS_ALARM, 4, new Label("Tab " + iter));
}

Button test = new Button("Test");
test.addActionListener(e -> {
    t.getTabsContainer().getComponentAt(18).requestFocus();
    t.setSelectedIndex(18, true);
});
hi.add(SOUTH, test);
hi.show();
```

Comment: Thank you, in this case `requestFocus` works, while `scrollToVisible` doesn't. However, to solve this issue in my app, I needed to delay of 100ms the `requestFocus` (using a Timer), otherwise it doesn't work. Note that I change the Form immediately before the change of the tab, maybe this was the cause of the need of a delay.

Comment: Instead of a delay try using a show listener on the form which should be invoked after the transition in was completed.